# How to know current pool size of mongodb nodejs native?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am doing some research in maintaining mongodb connections. please help me How to know current pool size of mongodb nodejs native.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current pool size from:

```
db.serverConfig.poolSize
```

Where `db` is the [`Db`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html) object returned from [`MongoClient.connect`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect).

The default pool size is 5.